# Set recurring notification for sms message

Tags: sms, notifications

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro Mini and would like to know if it is possible to be alerted to a new SMS message every few minutes until it is acknowledged.

Sometimes I am away from the phone and miss the initial alert.

Comment: It doesn't stay up in the notification area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two more popular SMS apps in the market - [Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) and [GoSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) have options that allow you to set reminder tones and LED flashing to alert a user to unseen messages. Lots of configurable options in both apps.

Answer (score 1):

Xperia mini pro has LED light that blinks in different colors. This LED blinks in regular intervals till you see your notification area.

This LED blinks for Mails, Messages, Missed Calls, etc. I guess by default it works. There is no need to enable it manually.

Coming to sound alert there is an application [Notification Plus](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jmoyer.NotificationPlus) which does this job.

Answer (score 0):

This small app may be what you wanted : https://market.android.com/details?id=os.checknew